# Font icons acting weird

Tags: css, font-awesome

My site: http://www.getmpango.com

I'm using two font icons, [font awesome](http://www.fontawesome.io) and [ligature symbols](http://kudakurage.com/ligature_symbols/).
When I load the site at startup with no cache, the icons don't load - both of them. If I reload the home page they don't change either but if I load any other page, then they all load.

I have linked them correctly since they are loading on other pages, I just can't understand why they don't show at startup (no cache).

#### EDIT

This is how it looks on first load:
Notice the green boxes - that's ligature symbols icon font.
The red boxes are font-awesome icon font.

[image]

This is how it's supposed to look - or looks after another page loads.

[image]

Comment: The icons all seem to load fine first time for me (OSX / Firefox)

Comment: @SimonMason Added images for explanation.